# Set jQuery DatePicker minDate using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have the following code to set the minDate of DatePicker but It does not work.

```
$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker('option','minDate',<?php echo $checkin ?>);
$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker();
```

Example if the value of $checkin is "7/29/2012", so the user cannot choose date less than "7/29/2012".

Any idea on this?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: i have already read that documentation but I can't understand this parameter "new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)". How can I put the variable for example w/ a value of "7/29/2012".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTnr5/1/

You have to define the datepicker before setting the option and you must quote the date string.

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Comment: But the minimum date needs to be provided in PHP not hardcoded in JS.

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
<?php $date = new DateTime($checkin); ?>
$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker('option','minDate', new Date(<?php echo $date->format('Y'); ?>, <?php echo $date->format('m'); ?>, <?php echo $date->format('d'); ?>));
```